# Lexical error on line 1: Unrecognized text. Erroneous area: 1: 0 - none. Heroku, Scss, React

Tags: reactjs, heroku, sass

I'm stuck, looked for it some time to solve this problem but couldn't.

When I run build, it fails because of Lexical error on line 1: Unrecognized text. Erroneous area: 1: 0 - none. No idea what is wrong in scss and couldn't fine the same problem "1: 0" by searching.

```
-----> Build
       Running build
       
       > ecommerce-store@1.0.0 build
       > cd frontend && npm install && npm run build
       
       
       added 1951 packages, and audited 1952 packages in 54s
       
       129 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       
       found 0 vulnerabilities
       
       > frontend@0.1.0 build
       > react-scripts build
       
       Creating an optimized production build...
       Failed to compile.
       
       Lexical error on line 1: Unrecognized text.
         Erroneous area:
       1: 0 - none
       ^......^
       CompileError: Begins at CSS selector undefined
       
       
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /tmp/build_5c229236/frontend
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c react-scripts build
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.GNGeo/_logs/2021-02-08T20_27_19_656Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /tmp/build_5c229236
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c cd frontend && npm install && npm run build
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.GNGeo/_logs/2021-02-08T20_27_19_675Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

package-lock.json in frontend

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-google-maps/api": "^2.1.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-external-link": "^1.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.1.0",
    "react-multi-carousel": "^2.6.1",
    "react-paypal-button-v2": "^2.6.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

custom.scss

```
$theme-colors: (
  "white": #fff,
  "customed-black": #242424
);

$link-color: black;
$link-decoration: none;
$link-hover-decoration: none;

$font-family-sans-serif: sans-serif;
$font-size-base: 0.75rem;
$border-radius: 0;

$card-border-width: none;

$btn-border-radius-lg: 0;
$btn-border-radius-sm: 0;
$btn-font-size-sm: 0.75rem;
$btn-font-size-lg: 0.75rem;

@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

index.scss

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

#root {
  height: 100%;
}

.container{
  padding-top: 20px !important;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .container{
    padding-top: 50px !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  .container-mobile {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    padding-top: 0 !important;
  }
  .row-mobile {
    margin: 0 !important;
  }
  .col-mobile {
    padding-right: 0 !important;
    padding-left: 0 !important;
  }
  .card-mobile {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  }
  .product-carousel {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .form-screens {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .form-screens {
    padding-top: 40px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  .form-screens {
    padding-top: 0;
  }
}

.form-screens .col {
  padding-left: 0 !important;
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}

.form-screens h2 {
  margin-bottom: 20px
}


.title-screens {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .hide-large {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .hide-medium {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .hide-small {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

.hide-mobile {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .infobox-hide {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  .col-no-padding {
    padding: 0 !important;
  }
}

.top-margin {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.margin-top {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.margin-bottom {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.margin-right {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.remove-margin-top {
  margin-top: 0 !important;
}

.title-margin-bottom {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .setting-margin-top {
    margin-top: 40px;
  }
}

/* Navbars */

.navbar-center {
  display: block !important;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 40px;
}

.navbar-margin {
  padding-right: 31px !important;
  padding-left: 31px !important;
  margin-bottom: 20px !important;
}
.navbar-search-form {
  margin-right: 8px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .navbar-margin {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-right: 56px !important;
    padding-left: 56px !important;
  }
  .navbar-search-form {
    margin-right: 8px;
  }
}

.badge {
  background-color: #f02020;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 0.2rem 0.7rem;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  margin-left: 0.2rem;
}

/* Aside */

aside {
  position: fixed;
  width: 30rem;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #efefef;
  z-index: 1000;
  transform: translateX(-30rem);
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
aside.open {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
.open-sidebar {
  font-size: 3rem;
  padding: 0.2rem 0.5rem;
  margin: 0 0.5rem;
  background: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.open-sidebar:hover {
  border-color: #ffffff;
}

.close-sidebar {
  padding: 0.3rem 0.8rem;
}

/* Cover */

.carousel-control-next-icon {
  display: none !important;
}

.carousel-control-prev-icon {
  display: none !important;
}

/* Card */

.card {
  margin: 20px auto;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-align: center;
}

.card-title {
  font-weight: bold !important;
}

.card-text {
  padding-bottom: 16px;
}

.zoom {
  transition: transform .3s;
}

.zoom:hover {
  -ms-transform: scale(0.5);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.5); 
  transform: scale(1.1); 
}

/* Button */ 

.btn-weight {
  font-weight: bold !important;
}

.long-button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  font-weight: bold !important;
}

.long-button h4 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.half-long-button {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
}

.half-long-button h4 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.half-width {
  width: 50%;
}

.full-width {
  width: 100%;
}

.to-the-right {
  text-align: right;
}

/* Input */

.label-hide {
  display: none;
}

/* Product Description */

.margin-top h3 {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

/* Product Size Description */ 

.main-product-size-description {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.main-product-size-description h3 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 576px) {
  .main-product-size-description {
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
  .main-product-size-description h3 {
    margin-left: -15px;
  }
}

/* Porduct Images Card */

.product-card-text {
  height: 50px;
}

.product-images-small-cards {
  flex-wrap: nowrap !important;
}

.image-center {
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.card-body-border {
  border: solid 1px #f6f6f6;
}
/* Product Delivery Details */

.product-delivery-details {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.product-delivery-details .row {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.product-brand-details {
  margin-right: 0 !important;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 7px !important;
  margin-top: 40px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

/* Product Description */

.product-description {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Product Carousel */

.product-carousel h3 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

/* Product Screen */ 

.product-screen {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.product-title {
  display: inline;
}

.product-title-sec-part {
  display: inline;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black
}

/* Spinner */

.spinner {
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}

/* Cart Screen */ 

.cart-item-header {
  margin: 0 !important;
  text-align: center;
}

.cart-details-header {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.cart-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dee2e6;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.cart-item p {
  display: inline;
}

.cart-details {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.cart-details-total {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.cart-details-total h4 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .cart-item {
    border-right: 1px solid #dee2e6;
    border-left: 1px solid #dee2e6;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dee2e6;
    margin-top: 20px !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .cart-item {
    border-right: 1px solid #dee2e6;
    border-left: 1px solid #dee2e6;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dee2e6;
    margin: 0 !important;
  }
  .cart-details {
    border-left: 1px solid #dee2e6;
  }
  .cart-item p {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .cart-details-total h4 {
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
}

/* Place Order Details */

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .place-order-details div {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dee2e6; 
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
}

.place-order-details {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
}

.place-order-details div {
  border-left: 1px solid #dee2e6; 
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Checkout Steps */

.checkout-steps {
  margin-right: 0 !important;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
}

.checkout-steps > div {
  border-top: 1rem #c0c0c0 solid;
  color: #c0c0c0;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .checkout-steps {
    margin-right: 64px !important;
    margin-left: 64px !important;
  }
}

.checkout-steps > div.active {
  border-top-color: #f08000;
  color: #f08000;
}

/* Alert */

.success {
  color: #20a020;
}

.danger {
  color: #a02020;
}

.alert {
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 0.1rem solid transparent;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.alert-info {
  color: #2020a0;
  background-color: #e0e0ff;
}

.alert-danger {
  color: #a02020;
  background-color: #ffe0e0;
}

.alert-success {
  color: #20a020;
  background-color: #eeffe0;
}

.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* Map */
.map-full-container {
  margin: -1rem;
  height: 600px;
}

.map-input-box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0.5rem auto;
  width: 25rem;
  height: 4rem;
  display: flex;
}

/* Search Screen */

.search-screen .col {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .search-box {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
}

/* Newsletter */ 

.newsletter-box {
  background-color: #c7d3dc;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: white;
}

.newsletter-box h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.newsletter-input {
  width: 300px !important;
  display: inline !important;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  .newsletter-input {
    width: 180px !important;
  }
  .newsletter-mobile {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}

/* Footer */

.footer {
  color: #242424;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.footer h4 {
  font-weight: bold;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .footer h4 {
    padding-left: 24px;
  }
}

.footer a {
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding-left: 0;
  color: #242424 !important;
}

.footer-logo {
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer-logo a.navbar-brand {
  padding-top: 0px !important;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .footer-logo {
    padding-bottom: 40px;
  }
}

.social-media-footer {
  padding-top: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.social-media-footer ul {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.social-media-footer li {
  font-size: 1.5rem !important;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

/* Search */

.search-title h6{
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: left;
  
}

.search-option {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* Breadcumber */

.breadcumber {
  padding: 0px 0 !important;
  margin-right: 0 !important;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  border-top: 1rem #c0c0c0 solid;
}

.breadcumber-box {
  padding: 1rem 20px !important;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.breadcumber-box h6 {
 margin-bottom: 0;
 text-align: center;
}

h6.breadcumber-box a {
  color: #6b6868;
}

/* Pagination */ 

.pagination {
  justify-content: left;
  margin-left: 16px;
}

.pagination a {
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border: 0.1rem #c0c0c0 solid;
}
.pagination a.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* table */

.table-top-margin {
  margin-top: 30px
}

/* Contact us */

.contact-us-form {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

/* Message Screen */

.message-screen {
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.message-box {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.display-inline {
  display: inline;
}

.message-box h5 {
padding-right: 10px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .message-box-btn {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .message-screen {
    width: 50% !important;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 40px;
  }
  .message-title {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .message-screen {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
}
```

can anyone help me? Any ideas what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 6):

Try wrapping the sass variables like this `#{theme-colors}`. 
Check [Sass interpolation docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation).

Comment: I figured out what don't work, but don't understand why only '0' and 'none'. 

$link-decoration: none;
$link-hover-decoration: none;

$border-radius: 0;

$card-border-width: none;

$btn-border-radius-lg: 0;
$btn-border-radius-sm: 0;

Answer (score 4):

```
height: calc(#{$wrapHeight} - 30px);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i have used variables with fallback value.

```
var(--vw, vw)

Lexical error on line 1: Unrecognized text.
  Erroneous area:
1: vw * 75
```

So I need to change single value.

```
 var(--vv)
```