# Lexical error on line 1: Unrecognized text. Erroneous area: 1: --header-height ^....^ CompileError: Begins at CSS selector undefined

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, variables

I'm stuck when I run **npm run build** on my react app it fails with this error message "*Lexical error on line 1: Unrecognized text.

Erroneous area:
1: --header-height
^....^
CompileError: Begins at CSS selector undefined* ".  I know the error comes from css but I don't know how to go about it since all my Css code depend on these variables.

````
:root {
  --header-height: 3rem;
  /* ========================Colours =================== */
  --main-color: 250; 
  --first-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 69%, 61%);
  --first-color-second: hsl(var(--hue-color), 69%, 61%);
  --first-color-alt: hsl(var(--hue-color), 57%, 53%);
  --first-color-lighter: hsl(var(--hue-color), 92%, 85%);
  --title-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 8%, 15%);
  --text-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 8%, 45%);
  --text-color-light: hsl(var(--hue-color), 8%, 65%);
  --input-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 70%, 96%);
  --body-color: hsl(var(--hue-color), 60%, 99%);}```
````

Comment: It sounds like the transpiler does not recognise css custom property syntax?

Comment: i you use webpack you need a loader

Answer (score 0):

For me looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66109687/lexical-error-on-line-1-unrecognized-text-erroneous-area-1-0-none-heroku) issue, try to wrap sass variable with {}
you can follow solution from link below

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66109932/9524228